# expose partial data of a model for users and all data for admins, sails.js

Tags: model, sails.js, policy

I have a model "user":

module.exports = {

```
attributes: {
    facebook_id: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: false
    },
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: false
    },
    email: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    pass: {
        type: 'string',
        required: false
    },
    writer: {
        model: 'writer'
    },
    toObject: function () {
        return {
            name: this.name,
            id: this.id
        };
    }
}
```

};

I'm trying to expose the attributes 'name' and 'id' to all users, but I want the admins to see all of it, how do I do it?
currently it exposes just 'name' and 'id' to everyone or just to admins (depend on the policies.js).

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done in the controller. When building rest applications, I like to create "RestModels", objects which handle only mapping to and from http requests. Here's some good rest models for you:

```
//admin rest model
module.exports = function(user){

  this.writer = user.writer;
  ..........

}



 //regular rest model
  module.exports = function(user){
  //only expose attributes you want
   this.name = user.name;
   this.id = user.id;
  }
```

Then choose which rest model to return based on whether the user is an admin or a user!

Comment: 1) I don't understand how a controller can exports two functions.
2) right now I know if a request is an admin request by the 'res' object (I have a middleware that validate it).
3) "module.exports = function(user)..." results with error

Comment: those would be two separate files. The "Rest models" are just constructor files which parse and validate requests and responses.